# How to set static private IP in Azure web app?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

I have deployed an Azure web app and have integrated it with a Virtual Network. After a while the web apps Private IP has changed. Is there a way to make this IP static?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to attach Public Static IP to Azure App Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52157032/how-to-attach-public-static-ip-to-azure-app-service)

Comment: I'm not sure thats the same question, since this is about internal IP when publishing to the vnet

Comment: Could this help? I assume it was originally only for public IPs but it doesn't mention that it would not also work with private IP, so worth a try? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-inbound-outbound-ips#get-a-static-inbound-ip

Comment: after Vnet integration, I got the private IP address but it's changed after some time as per the subnet range I want to make those Private IP static

Answer (score 0):

The basic concept is that you will need to install and configure an IP based SSL certificate.  A self-signed certificate will work fine, so there is no requirement to purchase an SSL certificate to get the static IP address.  The caveats are that your Web App must be in either Basic or Standard mode and there is likely some billing impact when using an SSL certificate

Refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/benjaminperkins/how-to-get-a-static-ip-address-for-your-microsoft-azure-web-site
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-hosting-plans
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate

Comment: I have done Virtual network integration in the web app but as per the subnet IP range, it changes I want to make it static IP how could I make it?